# How to render a PDF file in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-pdf-api

Android does not have PDF support in its libraries. Is there any way to render PDF files in the Android applications?

Comment: This is good example for Showing pdf files. Need to refer Readme.txt file in below link for using this . https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Comment: here is an example of using that library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294833/2027232

Comment: you hva to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498937/android-display-pdf-received-bytes-from-service-in-web-view-in-android

Comment: @SametÖZTOPRAK did you figure a solution?

Comment: @M.SH of course look the my answer below, it works and dont forget to upvote :)

Answer (score 83):

Since API Level 21 (Lollipop) Android provides a [PdfRenderer class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html):

```
// create a new renderer
 PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

 // let us just render all pages
 final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
     Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

     // say we render for showing on the screen
     page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

     // do stuff with the bitmap

     // close the page
     page.close();
 }

 // close the renderer
 renderer.close();
```

For more information see the [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic).

For older APIs I recommend [Android PdfViewer library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer), it is very fast and easy to use, licensed under Apache License 2.0:

```
pdfView.fromAsset(String)
  .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) // all pages are displayed by default
  .enableSwipe(true)
  .swipeHorizontal(false)
  .enableDoubletap(true)
  .defaultPage(0)
  .onDraw(onDrawListener)
  .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
  .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
  .onPageScroll(onPageScrollListener)
  .onError(onErrorListener)
  .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
  .password(null)
  .scrollHandle(null)
  .load();
```

Comment: PDFView library is great, but note that it is under the GNU General Public, not the Lesser GPL. This *may* make it difficult to include in commercial software.

Comment: Yes, @Sam is right. Personally I had to use PDF.js because of the licence issues in older Android versions, but the rendering is extremely slow and it's difficult to make it work due to Java-JavaScript communication.

Comment: For older versions, is there any way to show them without downloading and storing the file somewhere in the app?

Comment: In this case you can try the Google Docs viewer as mentioned in some other answers.

Comment: what do i need to pass in as pdfname?

Comment: Could you make a more detailed example using `PDFView Library`? What should we put in `pdfName`? What do the functions `onDraw`, `onLoad`, and `onPageChange` listener look like? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just came across android-pdf-viewer-library (https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library). It's old, but has anyone here tried that and had any luck? It appears to be LGPL. Edit: I now see it's mentioned as a comment in the first post.

Comment: Added a new PDF library licensed under Apache License 2.0 to the answer.

Comment: may i know whats the use of  enableAnnotationRendering(false) in barteksc AndroidPdfViewer .

Answer (score 56):

```
public class MyPdfViewActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo);
    setContentView(mWebView);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really not very clean. For one, if Google ever decides to change their Google Docs URL, your app will break and you'll have to push an update for users to be able to view documents again.

Comment: this is only allowing me to view the first page, and the "Download" link at the bottom isn't active...any ideas?  Also, it seems like setPluginsEnabled isn't part of the WebView class anymore.

Comment: There are very low bandwidth limitations to this method.

Comment: This will not work if no Internet connection and It requires INTERNET Permission

Comment: It used to work. But recently, it keep showing "Whoops! There was a problem previewing this document" I guess the google had change some stuff at their side causing this problem.

Comment: For me it was really slow loading and scrolling through the document.

Comment: Can I open jpeg file url using the above one? https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://test.com/abcd.jpg

Comment: content (html) + pdf embeded can you ?

Comment: It's a pretty simple solution, but if one is to use a webview, I guess pdf.js makes more sense since it can be served locally.

Comment: omg... opening docs.google is just for online users...

Comment: what if the pdf is hosted on a secure server and we need to pass an access token to access it, is it possible to pass authorization header with docs.google.com ?

Answer (score 34):

I have made a hybrid approach from some of the answers given to this and other similar posts:

This solution checks if a PDF reader app is installed and does the following:
- If a reader is installed, download the PDF file to the device and start a PDF reader app
- If no reader is installed, ask the user if he wants to view the PDF file online through Google Drive

**NOTE!** This solution uses the Android [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class, which was introduced in API9 (Android 2.3 or Gingerbread). This means that *it doesn't work on Android 2.2 or earlier.*

I wrote a blog post about it [here](http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2013/04/pdf-reader-from-url-hybrid-approach/), but I've provided the full code below for completeness:

```
public class PDFTools {
    private static final String GOOGLE_DRIVE_PDF_READER_PREFIX = "http://drive.google.com/viewer?url=";
    private static final String PDF_MIME_TYPE = "application/pdf";
    private static final String HTML_MIME_TYPE = "text/html";

    /**
     * If a PDF reader is installed, download the PDF file and open it in a reader. 
     * Otherwise ask the user if he/she wants to view it in the Google Drive online PDF reader.<br />
     * <br />
     * <b>BEWARE:</b> This method
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     * @return
     */
    public static void showPDFUrl( final Context context, final String pdfUrl ) {
        if ( isPDFSupported( context ) ) {
            downloadAndOpenPDF(context, pdfUrl);
        } else {
            askToOpenPDFThroughGoogleDrive( context, pdfUrl );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Downloads a PDF with the Android DownloadManager and opens it with an installed PDF reader app.
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    public static void downloadAndOpenPDF(final Context context, final String pdfUrl) {
        // Get filename
        final String filename = pdfUrl.substring( pdfUrl.lastIndexOf( "/" ) + 1 );
        // The place where the downloaded PDF file will be put
        final File tempFile = new File( context.getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ), filename );
        if ( tempFile.exists() ) {
            // If we have downloaded the file before, just go ahead and show it.
            openPDF( context, Uri.fromFile( tempFile ) );
            return;
        }

        // Show progress dialog while downloading
        final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show( context, context.getString( R.string.pdf_show_local_progress_title ), context.getString( R.string.pdf_show_local_progress_content ), true );

        // Create the download request
        DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request( Uri.parse( pdfUrl ) );
        r.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir( context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename );
        final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService( Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE );
        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if ( !progress.isShowing() ) {
                    return;
                }
                context.unregisterReceiver( this );

                progress.dismiss();
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra( DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1 );
                Cursor c = dm.query( new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById( downloadId ) );

                if ( c.moveToFirst() ) {
                    int status = c.getInt( c.getColumnIndex( DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS ) );
                    if ( status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL ) {
                        openPDF( context, Uri.fromFile( tempFile ) );
                    }
                }
                c.close();
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver( onComplete, new IntentFilter( DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE ) );

        // Enqueue the request
        dm.enqueue( r );
    }

    /**
     * Show a dialog asking the user if he wants to open the PDF through Google Drive
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     */
    public static void askToOpenPDFThroughGoogleDrive( final Context context, final String pdfUrl ) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder( context )
            .setTitle( R.string.pdf_show_online_dialog_title )
            .setMessage( R.string.pdf_show_online_dialog_question )
            .setNegativeButton( R.string.pdf_show_online_dialog_button_no, null )
            .setPositiveButton( R.string.pdf_show_online_dialog_button_yes, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    openPDFThroughGoogleDrive(context, pdfUrl); 
                }
            })
            .show();
    }

    /**
     * Launches a browser to view the PDF through Google Drive
     * @param context
     * @param pdfUrl
     */
    public static void openPDFThroughGoogleDrive(final Context context, final String pdfUrl) {
        Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(GOOGLE_DRIVE_PDF_READER_PREFIX + pdfUrl ), HTML_MIME_TYPE );
        context.startActivity( i );
    }
    /**
     * Open a local PDF file with an installed reader
     * @param context
     * @param localUri
     */
    public static final void openPDF(Context context, Uri localUri ) {
        Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        i.setDataAndType( localUri, PDF_MIME_TYPE );
        context.startActivity( i );
    }
    /**
     * Checks if any apps are installed that supports reading of PDF files.
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isPDFSupported( Context context ) {
        Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        final File tempFile = new File( context.getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ), "test.pdf" );
        i.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( tempFile ), PDF_MIME_TYPE );
        return context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY ).size() > 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Download the source code here ([Display PDF file inside my android application](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2017/06/display-pdf-file-inside-my-android.html))

Add this dependency in your Grade:
compile `com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3`

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="View PDF"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf";
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)

                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hint: `assetFileName` pdf file should exist into `assets` folder

Answer (score 8):

you can use a simple method by import

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

and the XML code is

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>
```

and just declare and add a file to an asset folder and just assign the name

```
   PDFView  pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfv);       
    pdfView.fromAsset("agl.pdf").load();
```

Comment: How do you declare PDFView in Kotlin?

Comment: @NicholasFarmer check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613766/render-a-pdf-in-android-using-kotlin

Comment: Just be careful, this can add 16~18MB on top of your app. This library uses `PdfiumAndroid` which itself is already 18.4MB

Comment: hint: `agl.pdf` file should exist into `assets` folder

Comment: this library will increase your app size up-to 16 Mb. so be careful while using this

Comment: You can reduce App size Applying ProGuard and shrinking Your App and Build as a bundle.

Answer (score 7):

I finally was able to modify [butelo's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21383356/2821954) to open any PDF file in the Android filesystem using `pdf.js`. The code can be found [on my GitHub](https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js)

What I did was modified the `pdffile.js` to read HTML argument `file` like this:

```
var url = getURLParameter('file');

function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null}
```

So what you need to do is just append the file path after the `index.html` like this:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/data/test.pdf");
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/index.html?file=" + path);
```

Update the `path` variable to point to a valid PDF in the Adroid filesystem.

Comment: hi Paul, i have also used this example, but it's showing blank screen on WebView in API Level 16, can you have any about this problem??

Comment: Where is the pdf file stored ? You cannot load a pdf from the assets folder. You can load either from SD card or your app's protected internal storage.
Also check your logcat for any errors related to webview.

Comment: Uri path = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/example4.pdf");

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/index.html?file="+path);

Comment: @Paul i am using above code it's working fine with API 19 but below it's not working. Why??

Comment: Please see this for compatibility with older versions of Android: https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js/issues/1
https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js/issues/2

Comment: i have something like this in my web view, "Page: /" nothing else what might have been done wrong?

Comment: @Shantanu Paul, I did the exact steps you mentioned but the webview still shows: Page:/
Could you pls let me know what could be wrong? I am on api23 btw.
Thank you in advance.
My logcat also shows: AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/THE_FILE
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/index.html?file=/storage/emulated/0/test.pdf (0)

Comment: I realize this is a really old post, however the problem with pdf.js on android is still an issue even in 2019.  What would be nice is if someone provided a working demo on codepen.io or a code snippit here.

Comment: edit which line of pdfjs. that?
is what you mean is editing the viewer.js and put in which line of code?

Answer (score 2):

To add a little light to this, I would have to go with the pdf.js solution from Mozilla. Here is the link to an already well written implementation of this: https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer/.

Here are the edits that I added in my Android Activity:

```
private String getInternalPDFURL(String interalPDFName){
    return "file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/index.html?pdf=" + interalPDFName + ".pdf";
}
```

Here are the edits I made in `pdffile.js`:

```
var url = '../' + getPDFURL();

function getPDFURL(){
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("=");
    var pdfPage = vars[1];
    return pdfPage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get the thumbnail as `Bitmap` from a PDF file without using any third-party library.

```
private fun loadThumbnailFromPdfFile(file:File, thumbnailImageView: ImageView) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadThumbnailFromPdfFile: ")
        val mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
        // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
        val mPdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor)
        //check if pdf have no pages then we can't show pdf thumbnail
        if (mPdfRenderer.pageCount <= 0) {
            //No pages in pdf, can't show thumbnail
            Log.d(TAG, "loadThumbnailFromPdfFile: No pages in pdf")
        } else {
            //There are page(s) in pdf, can show pdf thumbnail
            //Use `openPage` to open a specific page in PDF.
            val mCurrentPage = mPdfRenderer.openPage(0)
            // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentPage.width, mCurrentPage.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
            // To render a portion of the page, use the second and third parameter. Pass nulls to get
            // the default result.
            // Pass either RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY or RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT for the last parameter.
            mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
            // We are ready to show the Bitmap to user.
            thumbnailImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to open and print the PDF using Wi-Fi. I am sending my whole code, and I hope it is helpful.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int Result_code = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
                String jobName =  " Document";
                printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
            }
        });
    }


    public void openDocument(String name) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(name);
        String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
        String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("") || mimetype == null) {
            // if there is no extension or there is no definite mimetype, still try to open the file
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
        }
        else {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
        }

        // custom message for the intent
        startActivityForResult((Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Application:")), Result_code);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, Result_code);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback){
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {
                String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()    + "/" + "Holiday.pdf";
                File file = new File(filename);
                input = new FileInputStream(file);
                output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                     output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ee){
                //Catch exception
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //Catch exception
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                    output.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras){

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }

           // int pages = computePageCount(newAttributes);

            PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Name of file").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

            callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no anyway to preview pdf document in Android webview.If you want to preview base64 pdf. It requires to third-party library.

build.Gradle

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0'
```

dialog_pdf_viewer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_pdf_viewer_close"
        style="@style/ExitButtonImageViewStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/popup_exit" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/HorizontalLine" />

    <com.pozitron.commons.customviews.ButtonFont
        android:id="@+id/dialog_pdf_viewer_button"
        style="@style/ButtonPrimary2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/agreed" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DailogPDFViewer.java

```
public class DialogPdfViewer extends Dialog {
    PDFView pdfView;
    byte[] decodedString;

    public interface OnDialogPdfViewerListener {
        void onAgreeClick(DialogPdfViewer dialogFullEula);

        void onCloseClick(DialogPdfViewer dialogFullEula);
    }

    public DialogPdfViewer(Context context, String base64, final DialogPdfViewer.OnDialogPdfViewerListener onDialogPdfViewerListener) {
        super(context);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_pdf_viewer);
        findViewById(R.id.dialog_pdf_viewer_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onDialogPdfViewerListener.onCloseClick(DialogPdfViewer.this);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.dialog_pdf_viewer_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onDialogPdfViewerListener.onAgreeClick(DialogPdfViewer.this);
            }
        });

        decodedString = Base64.decode(base64.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        pdfView = ((PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView));
        pdfView.fromBytes(decodedString).load();

        setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    onDialogPdfViewerListener.onCloseClick(DialogPdfViewer.this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the GoogleDrive option, sometimes it would fail to load the document and 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0', though it's documentation makes it seem very easy to load a document from a link, I failed to make it work. It was always throwing a FileNotFoundException, so upon further research I got to understand that it downloads the pdf, so you'll have to make it point to that document, which I found to be a bit tedious.

You could try using this library here. It is very easy to use and is still being maintained as of date, I don't know a few years from now if they are to stop updating it. It caches the document and you don't even need to trace it's path.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/open-pdf-files-in-android-without-webviews-or-intents-3cc960752cca