# Android PDF Viewer

Tags: android, pdf, viewer

Anyone else having problems with getting the source from the [Android Pdf Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/apv/source/checkout) ?

I'm using Tortoise and I always get something like "Error: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to   "

I'm building a PDF Viewer for Android and i got to this promising [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)... but I can't get the source... unlike many other projects (apdfviewer, daisyreader...). In fact i can see that the link is slightly different as it doesn't end with "trunk".

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

they use hg (mercurial) not svn

Comment: Hi, solved it! Just needed to get Mercurial plugin for Tortoise (http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/)