# How can I change the way the google docs website displays a PDF in Android?

Tags: android, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am using the [following link](http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://174.136.1.35/dev/android/1_android-Survey-Report-for-pdf-1200-x-768.pdf) inside a `WebView` to show a `pdf file` in my android application:

- http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://174.136.1.35/dev/android/1_android-Survey-Report-for-pdf-1200-x-768.pdf

This works, and displays the PDF, as you can see in the attached images.  The problem I have is that

> I want to disable the zoom controls, and the desktop and download
>   links.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

[image]

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761231/display-pdf-in-webview-of-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically opening a web view and loading it with a webpage from the internet, specifically Google Docs.  Without some special functionality built into the website, there isn't going to be way to get rid of the extra buttons, links, and labels you're seeing.  Instead of this, you could download the PDF that your link is pointing to as a PDF and try to display that directly.  There is a [stack overflow question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)