# Display pdf in webview of android

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm displaying a pdf in webview using help of google docs, with this `url`, `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=+location of pdf`. It's breaking the pages and giving navigation icons on top right. Is there any way to display all the pages in single flow instead of breaking them.

[image]

In the image above, instead of showing in 10 different pages, i want the pdf to be displayed in single flow, I don't want to use navigation buttons on top right.

when `&overridemobile=true` is appended to `URL`, this image is being showed.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append `&overridemobile=true` to the url.

Example:

`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=www.example.com/example.pdf&overridemobile=true`

This will override the mobile viewer and take you to the desktop version, which has a single flow.

Comment: It's working, but it is also adding extra thins as shown in my edit.

Comment: Well yes, this is the desktop layout. You could set a negative top margin to your webview to get rid of it.