# disable download option when previewing in android

Tags: android

[image]

How to disable download and desktop option when I am trying to open this in an android application.

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.WebView01);
String pdfurl = ""; // Url of pdf or doc file.

String weblink="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+pdfurl;    
mWebView.loadUrl(weblink);
```

Comment: @bumba-Just show your code what u have tried..

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761231/display-pdf-in-webview-of-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for full screen pdf

```
 private void updateFullscreenStatus(boolean bUseFullscreen)
    {   
       if(bUseFullscreen)
       {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        m_contentView.requestLayout();
    }
```