# Android: TextView with links to online file

Tags: java, android

I have a [CDATA] string that has a (a href) link in it which links to PDF file online (http://online.link.com/file.pdf). I can make the TextView clickable in the area of the link, no problem, but the thing is that I want it to open a ACTION_VIEW intent to view the PDF file locally with the PDF viewer. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's Possible :). Go through through the following links.

http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-open-pdf-file-in-webview.html

[Render a PDF file using Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)

May this solves your problem.

Comment: No. The URL is in TextView, it leads to online pdf file, and when it's clicked I want not a browser to open but an Intent to show the PDF within the app. Like handling the clicks over links in TextView. (and without using OnClickListener over the whole TextView).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Intents like below.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("file://" + aFile.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

PDF files will be opened in default phone viewer. I am not really sure if it works on emulator. Have it a go anyway!