# Android WebView PDF View

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to View PDF file within my Android Application. Currently I am using below code to view PDF file,

```
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.xyz/docs/pdf1.pdf");
```

I don't want to use above method i.e. Google Doc, as it shows light blue title with two small magnifying lens for zoom in-zoom out, i just want to view the plain PDF, where zooming is done by fingers. Is that possible?

Comment: this could help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android

Comment: working with PDF in android ??? be patient man you will require a grate stamina for that..BTW best luck..and you can use PDF viewer library for that

Comment: do you have knowledge working with NDK? if yes then i have done one similar project using muPdf if you want..:)

Comment: Kalpesh Lakhani - No I never worked with NDK, but I can learn, I did found out something about muPdf.