# Library to convert pdf to image

Tags: java, android, image, pdf

I have an Android application and I want to show up a PDF into it (without external applications). The only solution that I thought is to convert  the pages of the PDF to images. Someone has experience with that issue? which library do you recommend me?

I tested the next libraries, but I have had troubles:

1) [PdfRenderer library](http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.swinglabs/pdf-renderer/) does not work with modern PDF

2) jPDFImages not work in Android (works in java desktop application)

Sorry for my English

Comment: You can take a look into iText pdf, it is free as long as you dont charge for your product/services

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android

Comment: Also check this library: http://code.google.com/p/apv/

Comment: @ns47731 The gratis version iText is licensed under AGPL, which allows charging money, though it also requires code distributed with it to be licensed as GPL or AGPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend use this library,  [android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)

Answer (score 2):

I'm expanding on the accpeted answer and providing a complete solution.

Using this library: [android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) and the following code, you can reliably convert the PDF pages into images (JPG, PNG):

```
DecodeServiceBase decodeService = new DecodeServiceBase(new PdfContext());
decodeService.setContentResolver(mContext.getContentResolver());

// a bit long running
decodeService.open(Uri.fromFile(pdf));

int pageCount = decodeService.getPageCount();
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
    PdfPage page = decodeService.getPage(i);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, 1, 1);

    // do a fit center to 1920x1080
    double scaleBy = Math.min(AndroidUtils.PHOTO_WIDTH_PIXELS / (double) page.getWidth(), //
            AndroidUtils.PHOTO_HEIGHT_PIXELS / (double) page.getHeight());
    int with = (int) (page.getWidth() * scaleBy);
    int height = (int) (page.getHeight() * scaleBy);

    // you can change these values as you to zoom in/out
    // and even distort (scale without maintaining the aspect ratio)
    // the resulting images

    // Long running
    Bitmap bitmap = page.renderBitmap(with, height, rectF);

    try {
        File outputFile = new File(mOutputDir, System.currentTimeMillis() + FileUtils.DOT_JPEG);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        // a bit long running
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogWrapper.fatalError(e);
    }
}
```

You should do this work in the background i.e. by using an `AsyncTask` or something similar as quite a few methods take computation or IO time (I have marked them in comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MuPDF**. Here is a link that describes how to build MuPDF for android: http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android