# Displaying a pdf file in-app in android activity

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to display pdf book in my activity but cant seem to find the right library that does help perfectly. Iv tried PDFViewer.jar [PdfViewer](http://www.ziddu.com/download/19248664/PdfViewer.jar.html)

but it doesnt display all pdf files, not good enough. Tried using qPDF [qPDF](http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/guide/#QPDFViewerView) which would have been perfect if it was free or even affordable, but its too expensive. Ive checked other libraries too but nothing seems to do the job perfectly.

Please help me suggest a library or any other format i can read books from and a corresponding library that can help me. Can i use Epub? Thanks

Comment: I think this question has been already well explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code from here([Display PDF file inside my android application](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/display-pdf-file-inside-my-android-application/))

Add this dependency

> compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'

**MainActivity.java**

```
package pdfviewer.pdfviewer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf";
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)

                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

}
```