# How to create an PDF reader for Android without text editing

Tags: android, pdf

i wanted to develop a android mobile app that the user reads a PDFs document in my reader it should block text selection, copying, pasting etc. my app should be only used to read the PDFs document. could any one please help me in this??.

Comment: other helpful info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this open source library 
https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview