# Open online pdf file through android intent?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

Currently I have a pdf `url`, and I would like to simply using the intent to open it, however, it does not work if I put the `url` in `intent`

My code is like this, it always throw  `ActivityNotFoundException`  error

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(law.url), "application/pdf");

try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Utility.showErrorDialog(
        ctx,ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sys_in, 
        ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.err_no_pdf_reader), 
        ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.close));
}
```

Also I tried the goolge doc approach but my client reject this, so I am not using this method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" 
+ publish.get(Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag())).pdfURL), "text/html");  
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks for help

***Log cat error Update***

```
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://oshc.zizsoft.com/oshc_testing.pdf typ=application/pdf }
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1568)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1439)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3356)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3317)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:848)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at com.example.oshpedia.Fragment.Shelf$4.onItemClick(Shelf.java:142)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AbsHListView.performItemClick(AbsHListView.java:972)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AbsHListView$PerformClick.run(AbsHListView.java:2511)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AbsHListView$1.run(AbsHListView.java:3200)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4882)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
04-23 18:18:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: First example should work. Post the full "ActivityNotFoundException" stack trace please.

Comment: hi what is your suggestion : Open online pdf file through android intent? which is best method

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can view or download the pdf by either of the two ways i.e by opening it in device in-built browser or in the webview by embedding it in your app.

To open the pdf in browser,

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Instead to open in webview,

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(pdf_url);
```

Comment: @Tuhin Subhra How you have solved web page is not available issue

Comment: webView.loadUrl() with Google docs is not recommended as mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861538/1177865

Comment: Note: It is WebView not Webview. (import from android.webkit.WebView)

Answer (score 43):

Best practice is wrapping your `Intent` to `Chooser` before starting. It provides users with built-in application selection dialog and lets avoid `ActivityNotFoundException`

Here a little example:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(msg.getData()), Constants.MIME_PDF);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, getString(R.string.chooser_title));
chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // optional

startActivity(chooser);
```

Where `Constants.MIME_PDF` is defined as String value "application/pdf".

---

It is possible to ask `PackageManager` is this `Intent` has appropriate handling `Activity` or not.

```
public static boolean isActivityForIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution because it makes use of the existing apps to open the pdf document and also gives the user the option to choose which one he prefers. Not adding the chooser will break the app though if there isn't any 'pdf reader' app installed.

Comment: Simple and amazing. Thank you!

Comment: This helped me. I was having a link without pdf name, pdf was generated when we hit that url. In webview it stopped showing recently. Using chooser method I was able to show pdf. Thanks

Comment: this is a good solution but when I use google drive's link, it does not work. can you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70737697/8192914)?

Answer (score 11):

you can view PDF in web view like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse( "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdfLink), "text/html");

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's not work when you don't have a google account in your browser.

Answer (score 10):

I see that you are trying this method defining the data type:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

but it will cause:

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Use method without the type definition and it will work perfectly:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 6):

you can view pdf in webview like this

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?"+pdf_url);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - helped me a lot. But note that your code is missing the url parameter name, i.e. it should be; webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+pdf_url);

Comment: i am getting no preview available

Comment: hi,here along with URL i need to pass input parameters then i will get Pdf link

Comment: @JuturuYugandhar, this solution has a limitation. it can not display large pdf. this thread contains answers regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39866468/8192914

Answer (score 5):

Download source code from here ([Open Pdf from url in Android Programmatically](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2017/07/open-pdf-from-url-in-android.html) )

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.deepshikha.openpdf;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webview;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String filename ="http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
        webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                // do your stuff here
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**The actual error**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to 
handle Intent 
{
 act=android.intent.action.VIEW 
 dat=http://oshc.zizsoft.com/oshc_testing.pdf typ=application/pdf 
}
```

***This says that:***

1. You "`broadcast`" and Intent to let the system try to open a `PDF` file
2. The system does not find any application registered to be able to handle this type of file (`PDF`)

You just need a `PDF viewer` of some kind.

**Solution**

Get a `PDF reader` app or use @Mahendra's solution.

Comment: I have already installed the ezPDF reader, still return same error

Answer (score 2):

If you use Intent you will be directed to browser all the Time So ,
Use PDFView Android Widget to View Pdf With in an Android application 
*Assuming that you already have PDF Url* or *You can Pass the URL to this activity using Intent*

Step 1 : Add Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

Sync the Gradle

Step 2 : Create a Layout [Text View is Optional]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewPdf">




    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/ViewPdf"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 3 : Here is the Activity.java files code , Add URL to *pdfUrl* variable in middle of the code

```
package com.example.firebase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ViewPdf extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txt; // You can remove if you don't want this
    private PDFView pdf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pdf);
        pdf = findViewById(R.id.ViewPdf);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);

        //Intent inten = getIntent();
        String pdfUrl = "Add PDF url"
        //Toast.makeText(this, pdfUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        try{
            new RetrievePdfStream().execute(pdfUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Url :" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


class RetrievePdfStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>{
    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;

        }
        return inputStream;
    }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdf.fromStream(inputStream).load();
        }
    }
}
```

STEP 4 :
Don't Forget to change / Give the pdf url in above code to make it work

Comment: Thank You @Be Champzz you solved my biggest issue
Code really working smooth just i will add progress bar to know how much % percent pdf loaded

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.
it works for both ***.pdf*** and ***.docx***

```
 String pdfUrl = "abc.pdf"; //
 String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfUrl;

 WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview_cv_viewer);
 webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Page not loaded every time by http://docs.google.com/gview, some time showing only blank page.

Answer (score 1):

With kotlin using [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko), simply call

```
 context.browse(PDF_URL)
```

to open any doc file, your browser will redirect you to the doc viewer app.

If you want to use **Google Docs**, then append your pdf url as,

```
"http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=$PDF_URL"
```

Answer (score 1):

View document using below method by default application in device.
Here url is the docuement url.

```
val browserIntent = Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(url)
            )
            (view.context as AppActivity).startActivity(browserIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(URL_HERE));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PDFView the file first download then have to select the pdf viewer. But if we give the url of "asset" folder then it work fine. Same the siatuation in webview. The pdf first download then have to open in pdfviewer application.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the SkewPdfView library for loading pdf from remote urls.

First of all, Add following in your root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

}

and add the SkewPdfView Library as:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.naya-aastra:SkewPdfView:1.1'
}
```

Now Include SkewPdfView in your layout:

```
<com.nayaastra.skewpdfview.SkewPdfView
    android:id="@+id/skewPdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Load a PDF file programmatically as:

```
SkewPdfView skewPdfView;
skewPdfView = findViewById(R.id.skewPdfView);
skewPdfView.loadPdf(pdfLink);
```

P.S.  link of SkewPdfView library

[SkewPdfView Github Page](https://github.com/naya-aastra/SkewPdfView)