# Select file from SD Card from fixed path to mobile browser

Tags: android, file-access

I want to get a file from my SD CARD to the mobile web browser(chrome). I have the fixed path for it for ex `sd/ECG/12345.pdf` and I want to do it from the browser itself without selecting the path every time and just click a button which goes to that path every time automatically and show the file. How to do it?

Comment: If you want this in web app then you can't, you can only add a way for the person to pick the file using input type file or using drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this URL in browser

```
file://sdcard/ECG/12345.pdf
```

I'm not sure it's allowed in Android, but you can try this in click event,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/ECG/12345.pdf"), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you please explain we are not able to understand as we are trying to pick file from sd card without selecting link every-time and just click a button which automatically goes to that part and pick that file.

Comment: @pankajmalik I'm not sure what you intend to do opening this url on browser should open the file in browser in most devices..

Comment: If you are building an app, launch this url using Intent on button click event
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240469/open-online-pdf-file-through-android-intent

Comment: as I cleared in my question i have a third party native app, and when i click on a link on  my website from my browser  it opens that native application and saves a PDF file in sdcard/ECG/Folder/12345.pdf . i want to open this PDF in my website my by clicking a link by giving this path "sdcard/ECG/Folder/12345.pdf"

Comment: @pankajmalik Got it. In that case I'm not sure android allows third party apps to access too SD storage, but you can try the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

First, on Android 4.4+, no app has arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). This should include Chrome.

Second, your path will be wrong on most devices. The actual path to removable storage varies by device and manufacturer.

Comment: as I cleared in my question i have a third party native app, and when i click on a link on my website from my browser it opens that native application and saves a PDF file in sdcard/ECG/Folder/12345.pdf . i want to open this PDF in my website my by clicking a link by giving this path "sdcard/ECG/Folder/12345.pdf