# code to open url which ends with .pdf in browser

Tags: android

I have written following code to open url in browser but this url ends with pdf which I want to open in browser but i'm not getting browser option in file chooser.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(httpUrl),"Choose"));
```

Comment: Browsers cannot display pdf files. So thats why.

Comment: Why you want to open PDF in browser ?

Comment: @Heisen-Berg    because pdf explorer is throwing "failed to download error"  but on browser it is getting downloaded .

Comment: First download the pdf maybe with default `DownloadManager` then provide it to `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: Because that's a direct link to download a pdf. You have to download it then shows it in browser or pdf viewer,

Comment: check this link may it help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/23241690/7104450

Comment: @ShashankVerma thanks. Its working.

Comment: @Ragini you’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to open a pdf file from the site in the browser.

```
public void button (View view) {
        goToUrl ( "http://site address/director/test.pdf");
    }


    private void goToUrl (String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
}
```