# How to view PDF File From the drive

Tags: android

I have Some PDF Files in my google drive account so how i can view that pdf files in android studio using intent or webview. How i can do that.

```
 public String co="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kr3y_2EI8-uyDeMI5DpMFLnMQDVqI-3Z/view?usp=sharing"
 webview.loadURL(co);
```

this code is not working.

Comment: you can try searching about Google drive intent and open the file directly in Drive app through intent or content resolvers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open online pdf file through android intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240469/open-online-pdf-file-through-android-intent)

Answer (score 1):

> I think you are missing
>   `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

```
    public String co="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kr3y_2EI8-uyDeMI5DpMFLnMQDVqI3Z/view?usp=sharing"
     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webview.loadURL(co);
```

Or you can use:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kr3y_2EI8-uyDeMI5DpMFLnMQDVqI3Z/view?usp=sharing));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Also make sure the url is valid.