# Track page number of PDF being displayed in WebView of android?

Tags: android, pdf, tracking

I'm displaying PDF in webview with the help of https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer/ described here [Render a PDF file using Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android/21383356#21383356)

But using this project i am not able to track pdf file for example I want to track user when user navigates through pdf , i want to know which page user had been go through and how long time had been spent on that particular page? Have any of you done something with it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. little tweak in javascript and this guideline http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html from google helped.