# What is the easiest your to view pdf file in your app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I followed a video tutorial online about using pdf_renderer to view you app,but unfortunately i got a warning message telling me that pdf_renderer only support API 21 or higher version pls can anyone help me with a link or anything that will be of help.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27820255/2528167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to user 3rd party libs, or write your own from scratch if you're using API prior to Lollipop.

Some examples:

- [radaeepdf](http://www.radaeepdf.com/download/download-android)
- [QPDF](https://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/)
- [PDFView](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)

Thing is, most of them are paid. So you'll have to purchase a license for your app, use the trial version, or try to find some lib that's free.

**EDIT:** You could also try to use a `WebView` and google docs. But that's really not a clean solution, as if Google decide to change this URL some day, it'll break your app.

Example:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context_);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LINK_TO_PDF);

setContentView(webView);
```