# How to read, display, open pdf file in android

Tags: android, pdf, android-studio

I am a beginner of android. I don't know much about working with PDF and files. Please provide me resources that can be understand easily. Is there any third party plugins should be used? I have tried searching old questions but i am unable to know where to start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very good library [(AndroidPdfViewer)](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) for API 11+ that can open, zoom and have animations. 
It's simple to use just read the [.readme](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/blob/master/README.md) file.

It's based on [PdfiumAndroid](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid) for decoding the pdf.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer @jzeferino but i am unable open a pdf with many pages it shows error. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Are you using the AndroidPdfViewer? Can you share the error?

Comment: yes, I am using AndroidPdfViewer .And now it is working fine if any problem i will notice you. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a url to access that document . You can use HttpURLConnection class and read subsequent bytes through it . Here is a nice example [android download a file](http://zacktutorials.blogspot.in/2014/07/android-downloading-and-viewing-pdf.html/)