# how to read pdf online in firefox in android

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon

I tried to read pdf online in firefox in android, but instead of opening it the pdf was downloading. I tried by installing pdf.js addon but it was an older version and not supporting. Any solutions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728920/pdf-viewer-api-library-for-android-app

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  You might get help on [android.se], or, perhaps, on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you can find some solutions to a **programmatic** issue here:

> [Render a PDF file using Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)

The linked answer has been marked as off-topic due to the fact that the question itself contained requests for off-topic resources.

However, I think your question is **not about programming**, it's about **reading PDFs in Firefox** for Android.

PDF.js for Firefox has been discontinued.
Personally I found [Google PDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer) a good app for viewing PDFs with Android devices immediately after downloading. But I guess this would be off-topic as well.

Comment: Let me rephrase -- what do i do, If i need to see the pdf in a firefox browser, as in a chrome Browser. Programmatically, of course.

Comment: @GauriKesavaKumar you need a display library. https://www.google.com/search?q=library+to+display+pdf+online