# Render a PDF in android using Kotlin

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin

I’ve seen the thread on PDF with Java, but can’t find anything on how to do this with Kotlin.

Is there a method or do I need to use Java?

[Render a PDF file using Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/render-a-pdf-file-using-java-on-android)

Specifically the step where I have to: declare and assign the name PDF file in my assets folder

```
PDFView pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfv); 
pdfView.fromAsset("agl.pdf").load
```

I get an error regarding PDFView stating:
"Classifier PDFView does not have a companion object and thus must be initialized here'

I'm new to Kotlin and can’t for the life of me do this.

Note: Only using Kotlin as trying to migrate my iOS app to Android and as I use Swift was advised that swift to Kotlin conversion was the best way...whether this is I'm not so sure.

full code for my UserGuideActivity.kt

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView


 class UserGuideActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_guide)

     PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfv)
     pdfView.fromAsset("UserGuide.pdf").load()

    }
}
```

Following advice in comments about pasting into Kotlin file and having automatic conversion, I get:

```
package com.example.foundationdoctorshandbook
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView


class UserGuideActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_guide)

            val pdfView = findViewById(android.R.id.pdfv)
            pdfView.fromAsset("UserGuide.pdf").load()
    }
 }
```

Problem here is that PDFView is never used so the id pdfv is not linked

Comment: All of those would seem to be doable in Kotlin. What is your specific concern with them?

Comment: Java codes can be easily translated to kotlin. paste the java code in a kotlin class and the ide should automatically translate it.

Comment: Could you post your full code or maybe a full compilation error you are getting?